# Average Query in MS Access

Tags: ms-access, average

Help with average query in MS Access. I have to display the average prize money allocated for first,second and third place.
The Table Prize has two fields, "Place" and "Money". I am not getting anywhere so far i have come up with this:

```
SELECT place,'money
AVG 
WHERE Place=1'
FROM Prize AS Average;
```

Which does not return the results for the average prize money.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a group by:

```
SELECT place, AVG(money)
FROM Prize
GROUP BY place
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, with your assistance i figured this out    SELECT TOP 3 place, AVG(money) AS Average
FROM Prize
GROUP BY place;

Comment: If you are using `TOP 3` you may also want to include an `ORDER BY` clause. Otherwise there is no guarantee what you will get: the first three places, the highest three average values, or just the first three records of whatever random order they come back in.